# How to access a variable in a queue nested in a binary search tree

Tags: c, queue, binary-search-tree

```c
typedef struct {
    int lineNum;
    struct queNode *next;
} queNode;

typedef struct {
    char word[64];
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
    struct queNode *front;
    struct queNode *rear;
} treeNode;
```

so I am trying to access lineNum through treeNode, a binary search tree node, and front, a queue node

I tried treeNode->front->lineNum but vscode tells me "pointer to incomplete class type "struct queNode" is not allowed". what should I do

Comment: Get rid of `struct` in the declarations `struct quenode *front`... You've already `typedef`'d that identifier...

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that your structures are unnamed, but you're referring to them as named structures instead of using the typedef. The quick fix is to name the structures. You can use the same name as the typedef, which is common:

```
typedef struct queNode {
    int lineNum;
    struct queNode *next;
} queNode;

typedef struct treeNode {
    char word[64];
    struct treeNode *left;
    struct treeNode *right;
    struct queNode *front;
    struct queNode *rear;
} treeNode;
```

You don't need to use `struct queNode` inside the `treeNode` definition, because the typedef already exists. But if you want to drop the `struct` prefix entirely everywhere, you can typedef the structures up-front:

```
typedef struct queNode queNode;
typedef struct treeNode treeNode;

struct queNode {
    int lineNum;
    queNode *next;
};

struct treeNode {
    char word[64];
    treeNode *left;
    treeNode *right;
    queNode *front;
    queNode *rear;
};
```

I do note that based on the error message, it looks like you're using a C++ compiler, as C doesn't refer to anything as "class". So, in C++, you don't need to typedef these in order to use them without the `struct` prefix, as the named structure is synonymous with the type name.

So, if you're actually using a C++ compiler you can simplify to this:

```
struct queNode {
    int lineNum;
    queNode *next;
};

struct treeNode {
    char word[64];
    treeNode *left;
    treeNode *right;
    queNode *front;
    queNode *rear;
};
```